# JavaScript dropdown list with objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a dropdown list with JavaScript that contains actual objects instead of just a single value.

For example, I have an object with two members, `ID` and `Name`. On the dropdown list, I would like the name to be displayed for each object. However, if someone selects a name, I would like to easily be able to get the associated ID.

Not sure of how to do this without two separate containers, one for what's in the DDL and one that has corresponding indices for IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, select already supports this. Option text and option value are two separate things

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pg92tqka/

When you get the value of the selected option you can get stored id and by this value access the actual object (id can be index in array, ...)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize this was already built in. There are a ton of similar answers that are all correct but I'll mark yours.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<select id="selector"></select>
```

JS

```
var data = [
   { name :'david',  id:1 },
   { name :'daniel', id:2 }
]

data.forEach(function(item){
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.value = item.id;
   option.innerHTML = item.name;
   selector.appendChild(option)
})'

selector.onchange = function(){
   alert(this.value);
}
```

see the following fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1jcrxoy9/

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this, however this is my favorite currently:

### JavaScript

```
var data = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'Foo'
}, {
    id : 2,
    name : 'Bar'
}, {
    id : 3,
    name : 'Baz'
}];

var select = document.createElement('select');
select.innerHTML = data.map(function(v){
    return '<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>';
}).join('');
```

Then you can append the `select` somewhere in your body with all the options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `value` attribute for your ID.

```
var ddl_items = [{ ID: 1, Text: "One" }, { ID: 2, Text: "Two" }];

for (var i = 0; i < ddl_items.length; i++ ) {
$("#ddl").append("<option value='" + ddl_items[i].ID + "'>" + ddl_items[i].Text + "</option>");
```

}

```
<select id="ddl">
</select>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dap3x83v/